# Succulent leaves dying

Tags: leaves, succulents

I've had a succulent that I've propagated from a single cutting into several pots. Initially they were taking quite well but have recently had leaves roll-up and shrivel/die. Leaves are generally from lower down in the plant.

[image]
[image]

I initially thought that this might've been due to overwatering, but I've let the soil dry out for two different two-week periods and this hasn't seemed to have any effect.

Other things to note, soil might be a bit compact? I don't think that's the case but find that photo below. The soil is of the prepackaged succulent/cactus type.

[image]

As well, I'm in Canada and we're entering winter so perhaps this is dormancy related? I don't think this happened last winter though...

Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There don't seem to be any new leaves developing at the growing point. That is more worrying than the fact that old leaves are dying.

Take it out of the pot and look at the roots.

I would guess the roots have rotted (soft and brown coloured, not white and firm). The plant is surviving in the short term by "recycling" the water stored in the bottom leaves which then shrivel and die, but unless it can grow some new roots it won't live long.

Incidentally splashing water all over the leaves isn't a good idea, since it can mark the leaves (water drops can focus sunlight and burn spots in them) and water can remain between the base of a leaf and the stem, creating a site for fungus diseases etc to start. Just water the soil, not the plant.

If the roots have rotted, you could try cutting the stem at about the existing soil level, and replanting the top in fresh compost with the remaining leaves at the soil level, in the hope that it will grow roots from the old stem. Give it very little water until it starts to grow again.

Comment: Thank you! Will do!